# wget cannot access a site on local network, returning this error: A TLS fatal alert has been received

Tags: ssl, wget, gnutls

I want to periodically download the index page of a monitoring web service, running on our local network (172.*.*.*:) that is using a self signed certification for SSL.

I'm using these switches:

`$ wget --no-check-certificate --no-hsts --content-on-error --ignore-length --unlink --server-response --show-progress --verbose https://172.*.*.*:*/app`

And the result is here:

```
--2019-02-02 15:19:24--  https://172.*.*.*:*/app
Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Connecting to 172.*.*.*:*... connected.
GnuTLS: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
GnuTLS: received alert [40]: Handshake failed
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

How can solve it?

Comment: As the error message says, it's unable to negotiate a TLS connection. What version of GnuTLS are you using on the client and server?

Comment: @damir, I don't know version of GnuTLS on the server (I do'nt have access to the server), but on my client, it's the version prepared by Ubutu18.10

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command to solve the same issue inside a chroot:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```